# Docker Alpine image issue with DNS resolution (slow)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dns, alpine-linux

We have an issue on running an Alpine image (PHP composer which based on php:7-alpine).

It's running inside an EC2 instance on AWS, we notice that downloading packages take too much time.

it turns out is it a DNS resolution issue, it takes too much time to resolve the domain.

Example:

First lunch a composer container:

```
docker run --rm -it composer sh
```

Then inside of the container run:

```
time curl https://packagist.org/packages/list.json?vendor=composer  --output list.json
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  
Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  
Speed
100   174    0   174    0     0     58      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--    48
real    0m 3.61s
user    0m 0.01s
sys 0m 0.00s
```

But we put ipv4 explicit for curl command with `-4` option, it works much faster:

```
time curl -4 https://packagist.org/packages/list.json?vendor=composer  --output list.json
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  
Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  
Speed
100   174    0   174    0     0    174      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1359
real    0m 0.13s
user    0m 0.01s
sys 0m 0.00s
```

Further investigation shows that adding `options single-request-reopen` to `/etc/resolv.conf` solve the issue only for Debian based images, but not for alpine.

A quick workaround is to run the container and attache the host network to it by adding this option `--net=host` but we're running Jenkins builds and we don't want to add this option to all our Makefile for all projects.

Here what nslookup gives as result:

```
time nslookup google.com
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

Name:      google.com
Address 1: 216.58.207.174 muc11s04-in-f14.1e100.net
Address 2: 2a00:1450:4016:80a::200e muc11s12-in-x0e.1e100.net
real    0m 2.53s
user    0m 0.00s
sys     0m 0.00s
```

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you have broken IPv6 in the container?

Comment: as far as I know, IPV6 is deactivated in this Alpine image

Comment: interesting discussion here with similar issue I guess: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/56903

Comment: @sadok-f the issue that you reference address a problem in Kubernetes. The network model is different in Kubernetes and Docker. Although the discussion is interesting, it seem not related to the problem in this issue.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

A great explanation about the issue and possible solutions:
https://www.weave.works/blog/racy-conntrack-and-dns-lookup-timeouts

Comment: This is also a Kubernetes related article. Running a docker in VM is different because Kubernetes replaces Docker's network model.